# Downgrade R version (no issues with Bioconductor installation)

Tags: r, bioconductor, downgrade

I can't access many Bioconductor packages in R 3.1.1 and I am quite disappointed with that. How can I downgrade from R 3.1.1 to R 3.0.2 or to some other version?

Note that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589064/downgrade-r-version-and-r-package-bioconductor) is not good enough for me as I don't have any issues with Bioconductor installation.

Comment: In Rstudio it is very easy to switch between R versions up and down

Comment: Bioconductor supports R-3.1.1 so your problem needs to be better described.

Comment: This question seems very dependent on what operating system you are using

Comment: @DavidArenburg So how is that? Which setting/button?

Comment: @agondiken, are you using Rstudio? If so, download externaly R 3.02 and I will post some screenshots

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yep, I am using Rstudio. And I have downloaded R3.02. I noticed that when you download an R version, if you close your R and open a new one, the version changes. However it'd be convenient to know how you change R version without quitting R.

Comment: Go to: Tools > Global Options > R version > Change... > Choose a specific version of R > [Selecet the version you want] > OK > OK > Apply > Restart R

Comment: @DavidArenburg There is no "R version" under global options...

Comment: @agondiken, yes there is. It is the first line where the path to where your R version is located

Comment: Eight years later there is (still?) no R version under global options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As point by @Deleet, this is **FOR WINDOWS ONLY**.

For the rest of the platforms, see: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop

---

Go to: Tools > Global Options > press the "Change" button (marked in Yellow) >

[image]

Select the version you want to use:

[image]

OK > OK > Apply > Restart R

Comment: Hmm, I really don't have this in my Rstudio. Could be a version problem. [My version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/algons/coursera/master/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-28%20at%2014.50.00.png)

Comment: What Rstudio version do you have?

Comment: The menu is there for Windows, not OSX or Linux. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem is not clear enough, I think it could be similar to my current problem ... I am not able to install or use `Bioconductor 3.0` packages inside `Rkward 0.6.2` with `R 3.1.1`, but with previous versions of `R` there were no problems.

I do not know the reasons for this problem, but when I tried to install `Bioconductor` inside a console (`xterm` for example, I am using Debian 8.0) there were no problems at all.

I used

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
```

and it worked fine.

I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: takes ages to install :-|