# Equalize gray levels of images in R

Tags: r, image-processing, histogram

I need equalize the gray level to 128 of an image and save it. After I have show the difference between the original and the new image and show the histagram of both images.

OBS: If you do the convertion using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e4uy.jpg) image and upload it will be a great help for me now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an issue of your R version, check out this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913643/downgrade-r-version-no-issues-with-bioconductor-installation).

Otherwise you may want to use imagemagick if it's more appropriate for what you want to do. Maybe something like this:

```
convert [image.png] -colorspace gray -channel lightness -equalize -colorspace RGB [output.png]
```

Comment: This will equalize to 128 gray levels? In Matlab, the exactly function that does what I need is histeq(image, 127), but I need do that in R.